# Logarithm of a pandas series/dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

In short: How can I get a logarithm of a column of a pandas dataframe?
I thought `numpy.log()` should work on it, but it isn't. I suspect it's because I have some `NaN`s in the dataframe?

My whole code is below. It may seem a bit chaotic, basically my ultimate goal (a little exaggerated) is to plot different rows of different selected columns in several selected columns into several subplots (hence the three embedded for loops iterating between different groups... if you suggest a more elegant solution, I will appreciate it but it is not the main thing that's pressing me). I need to plot a logarithm of some values from one dataframe + 1 versus some values of the other dataframe. And here is the problem, on the plotting line with np.log I get this error: `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'log'` (and if I use math instead of np, I get this: `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>`)
What may I do about it?

Thank you.
Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

hf = pd.DataFrame({'Z':np.arange(0,100,1),'A':(10*np.random.rand(100)), 'B':(10*np.random.rand(100)),'C':(10*np.random.rand(100)),'D':(10*np.random.rand(100)),'E':(10*np.random.rand(100)),'F':(10*np.random.rand(100))})
df = pd.DataFrame({'Z':np.arange(0,100,1),'A':(10*np.random.rand(100)), 'B':(10*np.random.rand(100)),'C':(10*np.random.rand(100)),'D':(10*np.random.rand(100)),'E':(10*np.random.rand(100)),'F':(10*np.random.rand(100))})
hf.loc[0:5,'A']=np.nan
df.loc[0:5,'A']=np.nan
hf.loc[53:58,'B']=np.nan
df.loc[53:58,'B']=np.nan
hf.loc[90:,'C']=np.nan
df.loc[90:,'C']=np.nan
I = ['A','B']
II = ['C','D']
III = ['E','F']
IV = ['F','A']
runs = [I,II,III,IV]
inds = [10,20,30,40]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))
for r in runs:
    data = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index,columns=r)
    HF = pd.DataFrame(index=hf.index,columns=r)
    #pdb.set_trace()
    for i in r:
        data.loc[:,i] = df.loc[:,i]
        HF.loc[:,i] = hf.loc[:,i]
        for c,z in enumerate(inds):
            ax=fig.add_subplot()
            ax = plt.plot(math.log1p(HF.loc[z]),Tdata.loc[z],linestyle=":",marker="o",markersize=5,label=inds[c].__str__())
# or the other version
#plt.plot(np.log(1 + HF.loc[z]),Tdata.loc[z],linestyle=":",marker="o",markersize=5,label=inds[c].__str__())
```

As @Jason pointed out, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16968491/5553319) did the trick! Thank you!

Comment: You seem to be using `math.log()`, not `np.log()` as described above the code. Do these answer your questions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968433/error-when-trying-to-apply-log-method-to-pandas-data-frame-column-in-python  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23748842/understanding-math-errors-in-pandas-dataframes

Comment: No, I tried both. Neither of them works. But you're right, I should have given both examples, fixing it.

Comment: As @Jason pointed out, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968433/error-when-trying-to-apply-log-method-to-pandas-data-frame-column-in-python) did the trick! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The problem isn't that you have `NaN` values, it's that you *don't* have `NaN` values, you have **strings** `"NaN"` which the `ufunc` `np.log` doesn't know how to deal with. Replace the beginning of your code with:

```
h = {'Z': np.arange(0,100,1), 'A': 10*np.random.rand(100),
     'B': 10*np.random.rand(100), 'C': 10*np.random.rand(100),
     'D': 10*np.random.rand(100), 'E': 10*np.random.rand(100),
     'F': 10*np.random.rand(100)}
hf = pd.DataFrame(h)
f = {'Z': np.arange(0,100,1), 'A': 10*np.random.rand(100),
     'B': 10*np.random.rand(100), 'C': 10*np.random.rand(100),
     'D': 10*np.random.rand(100), 'E': 10*np.random.rand(100),
     'F': 10*np.random.rand(100)}
df = pd.DataFrame(f)
hf.loc[0:5,'A'] = np.nan
df.loc[0:5,'A'] = np.nan
hf.loc[53:58,'B'] = np.nan
df.loc[53:58,'B'] = np.nan
hf.loc[90:,'C'] = np.nan
df.loc[90:,'C'] = np.nan
```

And everything should work nicely with `np.log`

Comment: No, unfortunately, it makes no difference. Still the same error messages. (And my real data are loaded from a csv file, so the missing data should not be shown as strings.) But thanks, at least changing the example to not confuse people!

Comment: @durbachit Can you post a sample of your dataframe? Perhaps `df.head()` and `df.dtypes`

Comment: interesting, thanks for the tip, the data are of the type 'object'

Comment: @durbachit Then they most likely *are* strings. The `csv` probably has `NaN` strings in that column, which causes the reader to interpret the enitre column as a string.

Comment: Just as I said above, when I changed the strings to np.nan, it did not make any difference.

Comment: @durbachit That's because you were trying to use `math.log` instead of `np.log` as you stated in your description.

Comment: Nope, as I said, I tried both. It didn't work with either.

Comment: @durbachit Ah! When you do this: `HF = pd.DataFrame(index=hf.index,columns=r)` it populates HF with dtype: object columns by default. Strange behavior, to say the least.